# Can I disable election notifications?

Tags: feature-request, notifications, moderator-election

I would like to disable the notifications, but I couldn't find any unsubscribe button.

Comment: You let people cast elections and yet remove an opinion of mine about them? What reverse logic is that?

Comment: ["Opt out of moderator election notifications" on Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/299110/opt-out-of-moderator-election-notifications)

Answer (score 23):

No, you can't.

Stack Exchange feels it is an important part of how the communities are built and shaped and by participating you have made yourself part of that community. Therefore those notifications are pushed on you whether you like it or not.

At best, someone could make a userscript to hide the Moderator announcement posts in the sidebar, but your inbox will be spammed.

Sorry.

Comment: Until now I'v got _one single_ message for this years election. Even if I didn't want them I would not call that spam

Comment: @ThomasSchremser neither do I but this is the second time I run into cases where users somehow express their disgust about the election and its process that I reckoned it would be worth trying some hyperbole. Voting on this answer will elect if this approach works ...

Comment: If you're part of multiple stackexchange sites, and if you keep getting these notifications, it becomes annoying if you're not planning to vote anyway. And I have nothing against voting on SE sites. I just don't think I should be expected to participate, there is probably enough people who will do it anyway.

My logic is - why would I vote if I don't know anything about any of the nominees and/or if I'm not even active on these sites? And I don't have the time nor the will to invest more time, be more active and research these people.

Comment: The fact that someone, somewhere thinks something is important will not in any way force me to contribute beyond what I'm willing to. So the whole thing might as well be mutable.

I understand your reasoning, but I respectfully disagree with it. And I hope this comment helps people better understand our point of view as well.

Comment: It is a notification, not a gun to your head ....

Comment: That's not the point ....

Comment: I don't understand why this is pushed on people like me, who have no idea who any of the candidates are, and don't visit stack exchange very actively. If Stack Exchange really needs me to vote based solely on how well-written the personal statement is, then so be it, but I think that's more harmful than good for people who actually do use this site as a community. (BTW, this cycle I have 4 election notifications and one email. Not sure how some people are getting away with one single notification.)

Comment: @Score_Under It is "pushed" on people like you because you are a valuable contributor on this site and we feel you should be able  to have some influence on how the site is governed. I don't understand why users that actively use the site have such a pushback to a once in a year event.

Comment: @rene I think the misunderstanding here is conceptual. Just because I'm a member of the community doesn't mean I actively use the subsite or participate in the community anymore. As of right now, I'm a member of **94** communities, needless to say I don't actively contribute to most. If all of them hold a vote once a year, that's on average one notification every four days. This is useless noise that simply leads me to visit the site less — similar to social media sites that tried to increase engagement but ended up alienating a large part of their userbase.

Comment: @Etheryte I have a profile on 169 sites. When was the last notification about an election in your inbox?

Comment: @rene Since you asked, it was a notification about an election that prompted me to look this question up, about two hours ago. The previous one before that was in September. I'm guessing that you're hinting there is already some kind of a mechanic to this, but I think that's missing the forest for the trees. Even Facebook, of all things, allows you to unsubscribe from notifications you don't want, I don't see why SE would be the exception.

Comment: @Etheryte so instead of every four days you get an notification every other month. Yes, that seems very noisy. Besides that I stand by my point that elections are important and infrequent enough to be missed I don't buy the *facebook does this, so we need this as well*. Facebook has 100 devs working on their platform. SE has 4 working in public Q/A. So that is the exception. And also my motivation to not support the feature request. There are more pressing issues to be addressed. Reducing notifications that happen every other month is not one of those issues.

Comment: @rene I think we will fundamentally disagree when you try to rationalize a decision as something else, when in the end it's a lack of resources, nothing else.

Comment: @Etheryte you brought in Facebook, not me. What we disagree on is that I look at this from a community perspective, you from a single user perspective. Both are valid perspectives. Hard to find a middle ground.

Comment: @rene I don't really see how your quip about Facebook is relevant? There is nothing beneficial to a community in not allow disabling notifications. That is purely a resource problem and trying to paint it in any other colors is simply misleading.

Comment: @Etheryte neither do I understand how your quip about Facebook is relevant. There **is ** something beneficial to a community to not be able to opt out of some notifications. Elections of our moderators is an essential mechanism for how this community works. I think it is critical that everyone eligible gets notified of this important event. On each election they can then make a new judgement call whether they vote this time or not.